# How to show a NULL value instead of deleting the entire row when the selected variable isn't there

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to link two tables in the same database using a third.

The first table is product and has the productcode. The second table is shop and has the shopcode.
The third table has the shopcode and corresponding productcode.

However not all products are sold and now it just deletes those products at the results.

This shrinks the list from 1600 to 753, however I want to see the list of products and the shops are a secondary issue.

So instead of deleting the entire row i'd like the table to just say that there is no shop selling it by leaving the area grey or stating NULL.

I've used:

```
SELECT * FROM product, sells
WHERE product.productcode = sells.shopcode 
ORDER BY product.productcode.
```

I've tried to find it using google and a few of my friends but I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks all of you,
Jell0zz

EDIT: after Tamago's help i've got everything in the right table however on firefox atleast, another problem is that when there is no value instead of leaving the borders of the table it leaves an empty space, this makes it look like there are parts missing. Also, in the first colomn i put the productID, however it seems to only show the productID if it is in the sells as well, otherwise it leaves an empty space as well.

The code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bier LEFT JOIN schenkt ON bier.biercode = schenkt.biercode LEFT JOIN kroeg ON schenkt.kroegcode = kroeg.kroegcode'; $resultaat = $db->query($sql); echo '<table border = 0>'; echo "<tr> <td style = 'width:100%;'>"; echo '<table border = 1>'; foreach($resultaat as $row) { echo '<tr>'; $nummer = $row['bier.biercode']; echo '<td>'.$row['bier.biercode'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['naam'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['type'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['stijl'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['alcohol'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['kroegnaam'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['adres'].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$row['plaats'].'</td>';
```

It might be worth noting that t1=bier (or beer in english) t2=schenkt (or sells) and t3=kroeg (or bar)

Disclaimer, I'm not an alcoholic but I think my teacher might be ;)

Comment: Q: I don't think you mean "delete" - you're just doing a query ("select").  Correct?  SUGGESTION: Perhaps an ["outer join"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Products t1

LEFT JOIN myBridgeTable t2
ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID

LEFT JOIN Shops t3
ON t2.ShopID = t3.ShopID
```

Comment: Excellent!  @user1459622 - this is what I meant by ["outer join"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins).

Comment: I assume t1 is product and t2 is sells, however what is mybridgetable?
EDIT:
A nifty thing called google told me to think before i post,
t1=product t2=shop t3/bridgetable=sells

Comment: t1 is the alias for Products, and t3 is the alias for Shops.  t2, which you didn't give a name to in your OP, but you described it as '...has the shop code and corresponding product code'.  It's called a 'bridge table', because it bridges your two primary tables (products and shops) together.

Comment: @Tamago, you are my saviour :D This is due tomorrow and that was the biggest hurdle I had to pass (don't laugh it's my first month of PHP at highschool)

Paulsm4 thanks a bunch too :)

P.s. updated the OP so readers will have more use of it.

Comment: Oh that's just great @Jell0zz!  I think there's a special ring in SO Hell for people who do other people's homework for them.  See what you've done!!!  No, seriously though -- learn like you mean it -- this isn't going to help you, getting answers like this.  Next time tag your post as homework, and folks can guide you to the answer instead of just blurting it out like I did.

Comment: @tamago - I definitely think the OP learned something here, so All is Well.  I can only wonder if the topic was emphasized - or even brought up - in class...

Comment: oh you have no idea how much things I've tried before this, so I have definitely learned. By using the left join command it no longer eliminates the ID's which do not fit the search but leaves them blank.
This way it is possible to have variables in the table that aren't specified for each product.

Comment: @Tamago sorry to have 'tricked' you, it's the first time here and I had no idea of this policy. 

However if you'd be willing to guide me to the solution of another problem that has come to the surface. On firefox atleast, is that instead of leaving the borders of the table it leaves an empty space, this makes it look like there are parts missing. Also, in the first colomn i put the productID, however it seems to only show the productID if it is in the sells as well, otherwise it leaves an empty space as well. The code will be in the OP

Comment: Haha, apparently instead of <!DOCTYPE html> i the genius that i am put <<!DOCTYPE html> which for some reason created the empty spaces.

It works now.